# How to refresh table statistics in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, table-statistics

I need to run a procedure over Redshift, that would check the number of rows inserted in a table each day. For that, I am using the `svv_table_info` which contains a column `tbl_rows`. This column contains information on the total number of records in a table. For my procedure, I would simply keep a check on the difference of the number of records in the table on that day to the previous day, using the `tbl_rows`. But, for some table statistics aren't properly refreshed as the `stats_off` column isn't exactly zero in the above svv table. 
 Now, I have a table `info_schema_table` which contains the information of the tables that I want to check on a daily basis. What I want to do in my procedure is that for every table in my `info_schema_table`, I want to refresh statistics at the beginning of the procedure.
I tried using the `analyze table_name` command in Redshift, but it doesn't update the `tbl_rows` column to the latest value.
I am new to Redshift and don't know how to refresh the statistics. Please help me out.

The complete details of my procedure is given in this
post:  [Remove loop in Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67774098/)

Also, the tables in `info_schema_table` are for insertion only, so their size is only increasing day by day.

Comment: What if people delete records from the table?  won't that mean you do not have an accurate count of the number of inserted records?

Comment: That won't be the case, these tables are for insertion only. Deletion isn't supposed to happen and neither allowed on the tables which are stored in `info_schema_table`. Could you please help me out in this @Max Gans ll. Thank you for asking.

Comment: If you look in `pg_views` you can examine the SQL for `SVV_TABLE_INFO` and so figure out where `tbl_rows` is coming from and see if it'll do what you want.  In theory, anyway - in fact that view has SQL so enormous and complex it's a living nightmare.  I don't trust it one bit, as far as reliability and correctness go.  Note that in general the concept of "number of rows" is a bit wrong-footed, because of MVCC.  In your case where you only add rows, you should be fine.  What I do is use `STV_TBL_PERM`.  This lists row counts per block.  Get the OID of your table (from pg_class) and sum them.

Comment: Remember though you need to handle `ALL` and `AUTO(ALL)` distributions, since they duplicate the table on the first slice of every node, and so will give the number of rows as being the number of rows multiplied by the number of nodes.  I can't explain to you here how to figure out the distribution style of a table; it's too fiddly and complex.  I recall one of the system tables (maybe even `SVV_TABLE_INFO`) has it, though.